# Ansible 2.2 : Replace module - Regexp expression to find not matching variable

Tags: regex, ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to modify the logging level in a file (present in several lines). To do so, I'm using the replace module of Ansible 2.2 as follow:

```
- replace: 
    dest: log.xml
    regexp: '<level value=(?!"{{ log_level }}")'
    replace: '<level value="{{ log_level }}"'
```

My problem is that it finds correctly the lines but it does not replace the old value.
Result for example with log_level: INFO and old value is equal to WARN

```
 <level value="INFO""WARN"/>
```

Expected result:

```
 <level value="INFO"/>
```

Is there a way to correctly set the regexp to remove the old value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
- replace: 
    dest: log.xml
    regexp: '<level value=(?!"{{ log_level }}").*/>'
    replace: '<level value="{{ log_level }}"/>'
```

Without `.*` you were matching (and replacing) only the `<level value=` not followed by `"{{ log_level }}"`, but without matching that latter part.

Comment: I have another context where "<level value=" is followed by another propriety let's say "default=true". With the solution above it will remove the "default=true" propriety. I would like to keep it as it is ? How can I do that ? I want this to be generic (it shall work with another propriety).